# Save images from drawable to internal file storage in Android

Tags: android, drawable, file-storage

I have some 10 images saved in drawable folder. I want to move them to internal file storage.

Is this possible?

I have searched a lot but, I only found links where we can save image to internal file system from given path, **but I want to save images from drawable folder to internal file storage in Android** and I want to achieve this through code.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Shrikant buddy u can follow this [drawable-sdcard][1] and [drawable-sdcard2][2].
   
 Thanks
 furqi


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558053/save-image-to-sdcard-from-drawble-resource-on-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198620/save-image-from-drawable-to-sdcard-in-camera-activity

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Saving image to sdcard from drawble resource:**

Say you have an image namely `ic_launcher` in your drawable. Then get a bitmap object from this image like:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

The path to SD Card can be retrieved using:

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Then save to sdcard on button click using:

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
```

Don't forget to add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Does it save in internal sdcard? I dont think so? Its for external sdcard.

Comment: Why dimension of png changed after saving? My orignal png in drawable is 180x40, but the image saved to internal storage is 540x120. Exactly 3 time height and width. Any clue?